# How to interact with the Local Storage in Selenium JS?

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber, local-storage

For some automatic tests I need to delete and modify some values ​​that are in the Local Storage.
But I don't know how to do it, I have tried this way:

```
Given('(the user )has an expired token', async function() {
 console.log(await this.driver.executeScript(`
 window.localStorage.getItem('key')`));

 await this.driver.executeScript(`
 window.localStorage.removeItem('key')`);
});
```

But from the console I see that it returns null.

**If I run the same commands from the browser console I get the desired result, but in the automatic tests it is as if it acted in a different way.**

*To perform the tests I use JS, Selenium and cucumber.*

If anyone has an example of how to interact with Local Storage with JS and Selenium, it would be of great help to me

For a suggestion in the comments I also tried this without success:

```
Given('(the user )has an expired token', async function() {

 console.log(await this.driver.executeScript(function () {
  localStorage.getItem("key");
  }))
 });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question could benefit from some code formatting https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and a little more explanation https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question with your suggestion ;)